# Превращение меню в кнопку при уменьшении разрешения

Tags: html, css, responsive, design

Пытаюсь сделать превращение меню в кнопку (пример: [аналог](http://calhoun.ca/) верхнее меню при уменьшении разрешения превращается в кнопку).

Думал, это делается через *media screen*, но всё оказалось гораздо сложнее для меня, и я даже не знаю, с какой стороны к нему подойти.

Возможно ли это реализовать средствами *html+css*?

Comment: Найдите в инете урок про адаптивное меню сделанное через скрытый `checkbox` + `label` - это и будет решением `реализовать средствами html+css`

Comment: круто, спасибо!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/5b7cn34n/

Comment: @soledar10, а почему опять комментарием? :)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот пример на `html` + `css` = [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/5b7cn34n/)

```css
nav{
    background: #000;
    padding: 15px 10px;   
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}
nav > ul {
   padding: 0;
}
nav li{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
nav a{
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
nav a:hover{
    border: 1px solid #fff;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;
}
nav label {    
    display: none;
    border: 1px solid #fff;   
    padding: 5px 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
nav label:hover{
    color: #f00;
    border: 1px solid #f00;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    
    nav label{
         display: inline-block;
    }
    nav > ul {
        display: none;
    }
    input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ label + ul {
        display: block;
    }
    
}
```

```html
<nav>      
    <input type="checkbox" name="menu" id="btn-menu" />
    <label for="btn-menu">btn menu</label> 
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">menu</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menu</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menu</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menu</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Пример лучше смотреть тут http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/5b7cn34n/ Можно размер окна изменять для адаптивности.

Answer (score 1):

Для моих нужд было немного некорректно, так как код необходим для адаптации меню под мобильное устройство, где при изменении разрешения меню должно выстроиться вертикально.
Немного изменил - меню изменяется по достижении 1000px, дополнил код, что бы вываливался вертикально.

```css
nav{
    background: #000;
    padding: 1px 5px;   
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}
nav > ul {
   padding: 0;
}
nav li{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
 padding: 2px;
}
nav a{
    color: #fff;
    padding: 1px 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    transition: 0.9s;
}
nav a:hover{
    border: 1px solid #fff;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;
}
nav label {    
    display: none;
    border: 1px solid #fff;   
    padding: 1px 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.9s;
}
nav label:hover{
    color: #f00;
    border: 1px solid #f00;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
    
 nav {
 text-align: left;
 }
    nav label{
         display: inline-block;
    }
    nav > ul {
        display: none;
  /*width: 100px;*/
  left: 0;
    }
 nav li{
    display: block;
    vertical-align: top;
 padding: 2px;
}
    input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ label + ul {
        display: block;
    }
    
}
```

```html
<nav>      
    <input type="checkbox" name="menu" id="btn-menu" />
    <label for="btn-menu">Меню</label> 
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Пункт 1 </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Пункт 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Пункт 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Пункт 4</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```